# send email when users log into nginx location

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to instruct nginx to send an email whenever a user logs into a specific location?

The server and the location would be, e.g. as follows:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;
    root /data;
    index   index.php index.htm index.html;
    ssl_certificate  /var/www/certificates/whatever_combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/certificates/whatever.com.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    #Heizungskeller web site 
    location /heizungskeller {
        access_log logs/heizungskeller.access.log heizungskeller if=$loggable;
        error_log logs/heizungskeller.error.log;
        auth_basic "Please enter userid and password for the heating controls";
        auth_basic_user_file  .htpasswd_heizung;
        allow all;
        autoindex on; 
        index   heizung.htm;
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there is any way to trigger an email whenever a user successfully logs to the /heizungskeller location.

Comment: You should implement that either in your app or have a script that reads Nginx's logs and sends out emails accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: 
Use some hidden tag like an image in index.html to 'mark' the visit.
Later, you check the logs with any tool like [LogSurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right: some processing of the log files will do. I was however wondering whether the Nginx directives, which seem to be quite powerful, might generically allow for triggering the execution of something (e.g. sendmail) as a response to an event (e.g. visiting a location).